# How to find out endianness of a file?

Tags: matlab, endianness

How can I figure out whether it's a big-endian or little-endian file? I just tried to write a big-endian file with matlab but probably it didn't work. Now I want to learn if it is possible to learn what type it is. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FOPEN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fopen.html):

```
fileID = fopen(fileName)
[filename, permission, machineformat] = fopen(fileID)
```

The third output, `machineformat`, tells you whether it's big endian (`'b'`) or little endian (`'l'`).

Comment: thx! btw correct format is [filename, permission, machineformat, encoding] = fopen(fileID)

Comment: @Gün Karagöz: Yes, you're right (though you may not need to know `encoding`). Anyway, please consider accepting the answer if it turned out to be useful.

Comment: (re-adding my deleted comment): According to MATLAB documentation the machine format value returned by FOPEN is the value MATLAB used to open the file and not necessarily the actual machine format of the file.

Answer (score 6):

There's no way in general to know whether a given data file was created using big-endian or little-endian byte formatting. You would need to know something about the type of file it is (if it has a standard format that only ever uses one or the other) or the [type of system the file was created on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Current_architectures).

When you use [`fopen`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) to open a file in MATLAB, you have to specify which endian format to use for that file using the [`machinefmt`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html#btrnibn-1-machinefmt) input argument. If you don't specify a format, MATLAB will use the native machine format by default (which won't be correct for files created on machines with different endian formats). This usage of `fopen`:

```
[filename, permission, machinefmt] = fopen(fileID);
```

Will simply tell you what endian format you used to open the file in the first place, which may or may not be correct for the given file.