# How to change endianness of a file?

Tags: matlab, endianness

I used MATLAB to change endiannness of a file. It works but endianness does not change. What's wrong with this code?

```
    f = fopen('139o.wav','r+');
    litEndFile=fread(f);

    fwrite(f,litEndFile,'int16',0,'ieee-be');
    fclose(f);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be working as long as the data file is indeed little endian, how did you check your result? With that construct I think you are appending the big endian data to the file. If you want to overwrite the file, call [`frewind(f)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/frewind.html) before `fwrite(...)`.

Comment: I checked my result by the help of [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187469/how-to-find-out-endianness-of-a-file). But now it is said that does not give the correct result. I'm confused now!

Comment: It works. It does change the endianness type. But 'r+' makes it append to the file. Now I'll check how to change the file itself.